# React Router refresh the url but not the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar

```
const NavBar = () => {
return(
    <Router>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand='sm' bg='dark' variant='dark'>
            <Container>
                <Route>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <Link to='/'>JOE BLOG</Link>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-nav-bar-nav' />
                <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.Link>
                            <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                        </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link>
                            <Link to="/about">ABOUT ME</Link>
                        </Nav.Link>
                     <Nav.Link>MY BLOGS</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Route>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    </Router>
);
```

This code is routing the pages correct. but you must reload the page to go to the page you want. The url is refreshing but the page isn't.

Comment: Can you create a reproductible app on an online sandbox (ex: https://codesandbox.io/) ?

Comment: Use [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch). Are you using `BrowserRouter` or `Router`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try replacing `<Nav.Link>` with `<Link>` imported from the React-router library. In any case, I recommend that you follow this [React Trainings](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic)